# Moscow Math Olympiad 1962 2 reflecting equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, reflection

I have difficulty to prove this problem from Moscow Mathematical Olympiad 1962.

> We reflect an equilateral triangle with one marked side through one of its sides. Then we similarly reflect the resulting triangle, etc., until at a certain step the triangle returns to its initial position. Prove that the marked side also returns to its initial position

and also another one follows: **Prove that the number of reflections is even.**

Comment: The followup is easy to answer and may give some intuition for the initial problem: suppose (WLOG) that we start with an equilateral triangle with one side horizontal and the opposite vertex 'above' that side. Then prove (a) that every reflection will have one side horizontal; (b) that if a triangle has the opposing vertex 'above' its horizontal side then its reflection in any side will have the opposing vertex 'below', and vice versa.

Comment: (Alternately, equivalently but in some ways even simpler: checkerboard color the triangular lattice of the plane.)

Comment: Thank you @StevenStadnicki, please check my comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's just sketch of the solution, following which, I think, you can do the rest.

For the second part, consider the following diagram. [image] Let the whole plane of the paper be coloured this way. Either the triangle began its journey from one of the blacks or from one of the uncoloured boxes. It's clear that it moves into the the contrasting colour at each move. So, to return to its initial position, that is, to the same colour, it must complete an even number of moves.

For the first part, consider a triangle and number its sides as $1,2,3$. Now, you've the whole set of possible paths in the diagram, so, you can mark each triangle in the box as $1,2$ or $3$ depending on the number of the side which lands into the side. Note that every side can have an unique number. This is a strong hint.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a triangular grid with the following regular colouring of its edges.

[image]

Comment: To add a little more explanation: In this coloring, every triangle has 3 different colored sides, and every reflection along a side of a triangle preserves colors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intuition, or lazy idea for your consideration:

Since equilateral triangles have angles of $60^0$, we can put together a prove based on the [cyclic group under multiplication formed by the $6$-th complex roots in the unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Definition), and considering the reflections as rotations of the marked side on the powers of $z^2$ (in red):

[image]

Comment: what if the reflection is outside of the circle? Can I apply the section (b) of what @StevenStadnicki has mentioned? it also helps to prove the second part (number of reflections is even)